# NserviceBus in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, nservicebus

In my Program.cs

```
   public static IBus Bus { get; set; }

   [STAThread]
   static void Main()
   {
    Bus = Configure.With()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .XmlSerializer()
                .MsmqTransport()
                .PurgeOnStartup(true)
                .UnicastBus()
                .SendOnly();

  var order = new PlaceOrder
            {
                OrderID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                ProductID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                CustomerID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            };


            Bus.Send(order);

   }
```

The Error I get:

> No destination specified for message(s): MessagingContracts.PlaceOrder

MessagingContracts.PlaceOrder is a class in a class library:

```
namespace MessagingContracts
{
    public class PlaceOrder:IMessage
    {

        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public Guid OrderID { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My end point is configured in app.config as:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core"></section>
  </configSections>

  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="MessagingContracts" Endpoint="MessagingEndPoint"></add>
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

My endpoint class

```
namespace MessagingEndPoint
{
    public class EndPointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
    {
    }
}
```

How do i correct that error and see my message in my private queue(MessagingEndPoint)? Any inputs on this error cause would be highly helpful.

Comment: Is "MessagingContracts" also the assembly name?

Comment: Yes, it is also the assembly name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this one did the trick & mentioning the endpoint name(destination) along the send method passes the message to the queue.

```
Bus.Send("MessagingEndPoint", order); //use this
```

instead of

```
 Bus.Send(order);
```